# the method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

Very strange - suddenly my app wont work according to Lint that tells me something strange

```
priceChangerFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "ttt");
```

where priceChangeFragment is a

```
DialogFragment
```

the class extends

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

Lint tells me the following:

```
the method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)
```

So - whats the issue here? - Actually, the signature is correct and have worked until now, that is ... I have a FragmentManager-object and a String object - but according to Lint its wrong argument list.

What is the problem and what has happened? I have restared Eclipse and cleaned the project. I do not know what to do?

Is something wrong with the SDK-version?

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What `FragmentManager` are you importing ?

Answer (score 0):

It works by replacing

```
 getSupportFragmentManager()
```

with

```
 getFragmentManager()
```

If someone knows why and why this happened - I would like to know :-)